# C#: Hook up all events from object in single statement

Tags: c#, events, delegates

In my domain layer all domain objects emit events (of type InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler) to indicate invalid state when the IsValid property is called.

On an aspx codebehind, I have to manually wire up the events for the domain object like this:

```
_purchaseOrder.AmountIsNull += new DomainObject.InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler(HandleDomainObjectEvent);
_purchaseOrder.NoReason += new DomainObject.InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler(HandleDomainObjectEvent);
_purchaseOrder.NoSupplier += new DomainObject.InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler(HandleDomainObjectEvent);
_purchaseOrder.BothNewAndExistingSupplier += new DomainObject.InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler(HandleDomainObjectEvent);
```

Note that the same method is called in each case since the InvalidDomainobjectEventArgs class contains the message to display.

Is there any way I can write a single statement to wire up all events of type InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler in one go?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at Bob Sammers' suggestion. The compiler wasn't liking the .Where method of the EventInfo[] returned by GetEvents(), but I've changed the code slightly to the following:

```
private void HookUpEvents()
{
  Type purchaseOrderType = typeof (PurchaseOrder);
  var events = purchaseOrderType.GetEvents();
  foreach (EventInfo info in events)
  {
    if (info.EventHandlerType == typeof(Kctc.Data.Domain.DomainObject.InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler))
    {
      info.AddEventHandler(_purchaseOrder, new Kctc.Data.Domain.DomainObject.InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler(HandleDomainObjectEvent));
    }
  }
}
```

After I added this method to the page, it all worked absolutely hunky dory. And I can add events to the purchase order object without having to remember to hook them up individually, which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do this in a single statement.. But you can make the code more readible like this:

```
_purchaseOrder.AmountIsNull += HandleDomainObjectEvent;
_purchaseOrder.NoReason += HandleDomainObjectEvent;
_purchaseOrder.NoSupplier += HandleDomainObjectEvent;
_purchaseOrder.BothNewAndExistingSupplier += HandleDomainObjectEvent;
```

Other than that - seems like the answer's no :(

Answer (score 3):

You can create an aggregate event in some base class (or in some helper class, or in the `PurchaseOrder` class itself, if you have access to it):

```
abstract class BaseOrderPage : Page {

  PurchaseOrder _purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder();

  ...

  public event InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler InvalidDomainObjectEvent {
    add {
      _purchaseOrder.AmountIsNull += value;
      _purchaseOrder.NoReason += value;
      _purchaseOrder.NoSupplier += value;
      _purchaseOrder.BothNewAndExistingSupplier += value;
    }
    remove {
      _purchaseOrder.AmountIsNull -= value;
      _purchaseOrder.NoReason -= value;
      _purchaseOrder.NoSupplier -= value;
      _purchaseOrder.BothNewAndExistingSupplier -= value;
    }
  }

}
```

And then just use it in the derived classes:

```
    InvalidDomainObjectEvent += new DomainObject.InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler(HandleDomainObjectEvent);
```

C# 2.0 and above:

```
    InvalidDomainObjectEvent += HandleDomainObjectEvent;
```

I've used this technique successfully to aggregate [events of the `FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events(v=VS.100).aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to do this automatically. I think you want something like this:

```
public static void WireEvents(object subject)
{
    Type type = subject.GetType();

    var events = type.GetEvents()
        .Where(item => item.EventHandlerType == typeof(InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler));

    foreach (EventInfo info in events)
        info.AddEventHandler(subject, new InvalidDomainObjectEventHandler(HandleDomainObjectEvent));
}
```

Then, all you have to do when you create a new object is this:

```
PurchaseOrder _purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder();
HelperClass.WireEvents(_purchaseOrder);
```

Don't forget that there is a performance penalty with reflection that will be apparent if you create `PurchaseOrder`s and other similar objects in any great numbers.

**Edit** - other notes: you will need a `using System.Reflection` directive. As it stands, this code needs C#3 for the `var` keyword and .net framework 3.5 for the `Where()` method (and - if it's not automatically generated - `using System.Linq;`).

As David has done in a later answer, it can be re-written without changing the basic functionality for earlier versions.

Comment: I couldn't get the compiler to accept the .Where method, but I've rewritten your code slightly and reposted it.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not doing very well today! Once again, this code is tested and I've currently got a working copy in my code editor. My guess is we're not on the same versions. You didn't say what you were targeting, but perhaps I should have said that this code will only work on VS2008 / .net 3.5 upwards.

Comment: 3.5 / 2008

I don't really use Linq, maybe there's something I need to reference?

Comment: Ah, yes, that could also be the problem. `using System.Linq;` should probably be in your using statements list. I get that automatically when I create new classes (from, I believe, the default VS2008 template), but there could well be circumstances when it is not included. I've edited the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to put the event handlers into an interface. Then you attach the interface:

```
public interface IPurchaseOrderObserver
{
    void AmountIsNullEventHandler(WhateverArgs);
    void NoReasonEventHandler(WhateverArgs);
    void NoSupplierEventHandler(WhateverArgs);
    void BothNewAndExistingSupplierEventHandler(WhateverArgs);
}

_purchaseOrder.RegisterObserver(DomainObject);
```

You either put this four lines into the RegisterObeserver method, or you replace the events and directly call the interfaces.

Comment: Not sure I followed this, but it still seems that I have to directly mention all the events somewhere, in the interface if not in the web page... is that right?

Comment: Yes, you need to mention all the events somewhere, but only on one single place.